# How to pass mvn test-compile hibernate3:hbm2ddl as argument of Runtime.getRuntime().exec?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a folder in local drive, C:\PK
I want to run hbm2ddl command for this folder.
I am ruuning my code using this,

```
Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\PK\\ mvn test-compile hibernate3:hbm2ddl");
```

here i am getting error like this,

```
Cannot run program "C:\PK\": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

and if i change the code to this,

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        File f=new File("C:\\PK\\");
        String[] arr=new String[1];
        arr[0]="mvn test-compile hibernate3:hbm2ddl";
        Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arr,null,f);
```

then it's giving following error,

```
Cannot run program "mvn test-compile hibernate3:hbm2ddl" (in directory "C:\PK"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Can anyone please explain what wrong thing i am doing here.?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is probably because you didn't add the maven\bin folder to the enviroment variable path on your computer. Also you call the command in a wrong way on the first attempt try: `"C:\\PK\\mvn test-compile hibernate3:hbm2ddl"` without the space between the folder and the command

Comment: I have updated the code now, provided mvn path, still giving the same error,  File f=new File("C:\\PK");
   String[] arr=new String[1];
   String[] path=new String[1];
   path[0]="C:\\Tools\\apache-maven-3.2.3\\bin";
   arr[0]="mvn test-compile hibernate3:hbm2ddl";
   Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arr,path,f);

Comment: I have done same like u said, and i got same exception,  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\PK\mvn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified